# JQuery animate won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to get list items to scroll up and down when I click on a link. I just can't get it to work.

**UPDATE:** Added a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marcbrigham/QmxWc/2/)

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    //console.log($('.nav-up'));
$('.nav-controls').on('click', '.nav-up', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //alert('clicked');
    var navHeight = $(e.currentTarget).closest('.horz-scroll').find('.block-nav').height();
    var el = $(e.currentTarget).closest('.horz-scroll').find('.block-nav > ul');
    if((el.height() - navHeight) < el.position().top) {
        el.animate({ top: '+=19' }, 'fast');
        console.log(el.css('top'));
    }
});});
```

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="horz-scroll">
<div class="block-nav-wrapper">
<div class="block-nav">
<ul>
    <li>
    <div class="wrap-box-name">&nbsp;<span><img src="../../../upload/1/img/arrow.png" /></span>&nbsp;Orinda Union School District</div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div class="wrap-box-name">&nbsp;<span><img src="../../../upload/1/img/arrow.png" /></span>&nbsp;Orinda Union School District</div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div class="wrap-box-name">&nbsp;<span><img src="../../../upload/1/img/arrow.png" /></span>&nbsp;Orinda Union School District</div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div class="wrap-box-name">&nbsp;<span><img src="../../../upload/1/img/arrow.png" /></span>&nbsp;Orinda Union School District</div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div class="wrap-box-name">&nbsp;<span><img src="../../../upload/1/img/arrow.png" /></span>&nbsp;Orinda Union School District</div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

<div class="nav-controls">
<ul>
    <li><a class="nav-up" href="#"><img src="../../../upload/1/img/prev.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><input class="nav_down" name="submit" src="../../../upload/1/img/next.jpg" type="image" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.nav-controls {
    right: 10px;
    top: 25px;
    margin-left: 37%;
}

.nav-controls ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.nav-controls ul li{
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 16px;
}
.block-nav-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.block-nav {
    position: relative;
    height: 130px;
    margin: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.block-nav ul{

}
.block-nav ul li{
    list-style:none;
    line-height:35px;
}


console.log(el.height()); = 175
console.log(navHeight); = 130
console.log(el.position().top); = 0
```

Comment: check the values of `el.height(), navHeight,el.position().top` your condition is probably false

Comment: el.position().top = 0 when i test your code :)

Comment: Yup just updated my post with the values from the console.

Comment: your condition is not satisfied, so it is not working

Comment: If I change the operation to a > sign it still won't work.

Comment: photos are broken. It gives me headache

Comment: I can't provide the images since it is on our testing server. The site hasn't been launched yet. But thankfully to JSFiddle you can put in any photos you want ;)

Comment: Or you could use a placeholder site to make it easier on the people trying to help you ;)

Comment: Here is the updated JSFiddle w/ images: http://jsfiddle.net/marcbrigham/QmxWc/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things before you get the answer.

1. You have to include jQuery in your fiddle if you're using it.
2. like [Chris Rockwell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1108292/chris-rockwell) said, use a placeholder site (I swapped everything to use http://placehold.it/)

Now, here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QmxWc/1/. Main thing that was missing was `position:relative` on the `<ul>` you were trying to move. But you also had some logic problems with your javascript.

CSS:

```css
.block-nav ul {
    position: relative;
}
```

JS:

```js
$('.nav-controls').on('click', '.nav-up', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //alert('clicked');
    var navHeight = $(e.currentTarget).closest('.horz-scroll').find('.block-nav').height();
    var el = $(e.currentTarget).closest('.horz-scroll').find('.block-nav > ul');
    if ((el.height() - navHeight) > Math.abs(el.position().top)) {
        el.animate({
            top: '-=19'
        }, 'fast');
        console.log(el.css('top'));
    }
});
```